# 301 redirects for all except me

Tags: htaccess

I want to have my site down for an hour and I was using

```
order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from my.ip.add.ress
```

but I don't like the default error page. Is there a 301 redirect where I can redirect everyone who is not on my IP address to a nice and pretty page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just specify a page that all 403 error messages should be shown:

```
order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from my.ip.add.ress

ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden.html
```

You can customize this page to look any way you wish.